# Lexer rule optional suffix not matching, when it should match

Tags: parsing, antlr3, lexer

Using ANTLR 3, my lexer has rule

```
SELECT_ASSIGN:    
'SELECT' WS+ IDENTIFIER WS+ 'ASSIGN' WS+  (('TO'|'USING') WS+)?
```

using this these match correctly

```
SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN TO
SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN USING
```

and this also matches

```
SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN FOO
```

However this does not match

```
SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN TWO
```

Whereas I have marked TO|USING as optional in the rule.

From generated Java code I see...
When lexer notices T of TWO, it goes to match('TO')
but since does not find O after T
then generates failure.... and returns all the way from the rule -- hence not matching it.

How do I get my lexer rule to match, when input has word with chars starting with suffixed optional part of the rule

Basically I want my rule to match this also (beside what it already matches - as lised at the start):

```
SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN TWO
```

Kindly suggest how I approach/resolve this situation.

NOTE:

Such rules are recommended in the parser - But I have this in lexer - because I do not want to parse the entire input by the parser, and want to parse only content of interest. So using such rules in lexer, I locate sections which I really want to parse by the parser.

---

UPDATE 1
I could circumvent this problem by making 2 rules, like so:

```
SELECT_ASSIGN_USING_TO
: tok='SELECT' WS+ name=IDENTIFIER WS+ 'ASSIGN' WS+ ('USING'|'TO')

SELECT_ASSIGN
: tok='SELECT' WS+ name=IDENTIFIER WS+ 'ASSIGN'
```

But is it possible to do the desired in one lexer rule?

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete  lexer grammar that does this (a [mcve]) - the problem might be in another lexer rule(s).

Answer (score 0):

An approach to get this in one rule, suggested by my senior - use syntactic predicate

```
SELECT_ASSIGN
: tok='SELECT' WS+ name=IDENTIFIER WS+ 'ASSIGN'
    (
      (WS+ ('TO'|'USING') WS+)=> (WS+ ('TO'|'USING') WS+)
      | (WS+)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Tokens match a complete char sequence or none. It cannot match partially and the grammar rule determines which exactly. You cannot expect a rule for `TO` to match `TWO`. If you want `TWO` to match too you have to add it to your lexer rule.

A few notes here:

1. The solution your "senior" gave you makes no sense at all. A
   syntactic predicate is a kinda lookahead to guide the parser in case
   of ambiquities. There are no ambiquities involved here.
2. Writing
   the entire SELECT_ASSIGN rule as a lexer rule is very uncommon and
   not flexible. A lexer rule should not be used for entire sentences,
   but only for a small set of characters to find tokens to assign them
   a type (usually elementary structures of a language like `string`,
   `number`, `comment` etc.).
3. ANTLR3 is totally outdated and I wonder why this is still used in your class. ANTLR4 is out since 5 years and should be the choice for any new project.

Comment: I do not want "rule for TO" to match TWO.

What I stated is this: 
I expected lexer rule to match at least first 3 words of input "SELECT VAR1 ASSIGN TWO" - because TO|USING at the end of rule is optional.

Comment: Still, my answer applies. A lexer rule matches fully or not at all. If you had written your SELECT_ASSIGN rules as a parser rule, things would change. Also for parser rules the principle applies that it matches fully or not at all, however when you split your rule into several parts the generated parse tree will at least contain those parts that matched (depending on how the rules are structured).